# Can you combine Jersey and Spring (@Provider and @Component)?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

What I have already working:

1. Spring version **4.1.4.RELEASE**.
2. Jersey version **2.14**.
3. I added maven dependency **jersey-spring3** and excluded spring from it (spring-core, spring-web, spring-beans).
4. Spring components are scanned for - `@ComponentScan`.
5. "Controllers" are registered in Jersey's `ResourceConfig`...
6. ... and are annotated with `@Path` and `@Component`...
7. ... so that `@Autowired` beans fetch (`@Transactional`) POJOs from database...
8. ... and Jersey with help of certain `@Provider`s returns them in form of JSON.

What seems to be the problem is that a classes annotated with `@Provider` stop working as soon as I add annotation `@Component`.

Was anyone successful in combining those annotations? If yes, then what am I missing? If not, then it'll be quite clear that I have to move to alternative libraries. :)

Comment: What are you planning on using jersey for? Rest?

Comment: @KubaSpatny Jersey has some good sides as well. Why do you hate it so much? Version 2.x is really decent :)

Comment: @R4J Oh no I don't hate it. I just found using `RestController` easier to set up with Spring contexts.

Comment: @Nebril and if you leave your "Provider" annotated classes without "Component" and test if "Autowired" works on them? Would that be helpful for you?

Comment: @R4J It does work - that's the answer I was looking for. I didn't suspect that. But there's a BUT: scopes don't work. So in the end beans are injected but scopes are lost. So this means switching to RestController everywhere. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think that using RestController could be the better way to go, this code (below) works - so my answer may be useful to everyone who is forced to use Jersey + Spring (for whatever reason...)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<EntityNotFoundException> {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(EntityNotFoundException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: One important note: injecting works but scopes do not. So the answer to question **can you mix Providers and Components?** would be **not reliably**. :)

Comment: Yeah, go with Spring Boot! ;)

Comment: We are using Jersey + Spring (no spring boot) without `@Provider`, should we add `@Provider` where expected (as `ExceptionMapper`) or not?

Comment: @user7294900 yes you can use Provider safely.

Comment: @SachinGiri What will change it I add it? it seems that Spring is handling DI, so there'll be no effect

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring's `RestController`, which was added in Spring 4.0. It allows you to use `Autowired` among other things.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/msg")
public class MessageRestController {

     @Autowired
     private IShortMessageService shortMessageService;    

     @RequestMapping(value = "/message-json/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
     public ShortMessageDto getMessageJSONById(@PathVariable String id) {
           Long id_value = null;
           try {
                id_value = Long.parseLong(id);
                ShortMessageDto message = shortMessageService.getById(id_value);
                if(message != null){
                return message;
           } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                // log message                    
           }                   
               return null;
      }

}
```